Is it bad idea to add new functions into an existing 3rd party library's namespace?
My code is using a library called "tf2" and it has a namespace of tf2 and overloaded functions like tf2:fromMsg().
Then in my code, I would like to add one more overloaded function tf2:fromMsg() but with difference parameters.
So I write code like this: (in my own code)
namespace tf2
{
void fromMsg(const geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped & msg, tf2::Stamped<tf2::Transform> & out)
{
  ...
}
}  // namespace tf2

I see some benefits, so that the user of my code use familiar tf:frmMsg() like other code which already uses tf:frmMsg().
But I also see some concerns: the code is actually hacking into the existing namespace and pretending it's a whole part but actually it's not.
So, is it good or bad?

It is practical, but might cause issues later if they add a similar overload later. So I tend not to do it

It can be a problem if there are unintended interactions - for example, if you overload a function, and code within the library ends up (due to being a better match according to language rules) calling your function instead of an existing one in the library.    Rather than injecting functions into a library's namespace, it would probably be simpler - for you and developers using your code and the library - to place your functions in another namespace - for example, Felix_tf2 instead of tf2.

It would work perfectly, and no danger could be made, but... why make all this mess? Effectively, it would defeat the purpose of namespaces, at least for your code. If you just need to play with td2 or something, to experiment for a short time, do whatever you want. If it is anything a bit more serious — think thoroughly about your naming.

Bad idea.
At some point in the future, it may violate the "One Definition Rule" and lead to undefined behavior.
You can use the using clause to help simplify things:
namespace tf2Extension
{
void fromMsg(const geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped & msg, tf2::Stamped<tf2::Transform> & out)
{
  ...
}
}

.....

void myFunction()
{
    using  tf2Extension::fromMsg;
    using  tf2::fromMsg;

    fromMsg(<Parameters That distinguish usage>);
}

Now the compiler will tell you when the tf2 library is extended and clashes with your function.
